Why Does This Website Has the isPartOf Property Under the mainEntityOfPage Property?
I am in the process of learning schema markup, and one of the Blog Posts I reviewed as a reference has the isPartOf property under the mainEntityOfPage property. The main Schema Markup type in this case is Article.
Can you help me understand what was the reasoning behind this decision?
Here's the code:
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "headline": "Hello World",
  "name": "Hello World",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "id": "https://example.com/hello-world#webpage",
    "url": "https://example.com/hello-world",
    "isPartOf": {
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "id": "https://example.com/#website",
      "url": "https://example.com",
      "name": "Example Website",
      "publishingPrinciples": "https://example.com/publishing-principles"
    }
  }
}


The article (Article) on "Hello World" is what the page (WebPage) is about (mainEntityOfPage), which is part of (isPartOf) a website (WebSite) called "Example Website".
In your example, "id" should be "@id". And you should find that the WebSite @id is the same on every page. That way, machines can determine that multiple pages that contain articles are part of the same website.

Thanks for the tips Tony. I am still a bit confused about these concepts but I will try to keep digging.
